# Is there a way to define betweeness that doesn't require two cases? ($s$ is between $x,y$ if, if $x<y$, then $x<s<y$, and if $y<x$, then $y<s<x$)

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, order-theory

Consider the proof that $(a+b)/2$ is between $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. The proof requires two cases, according to the definition of in-betweeness: $s$ is in-between $x,y$ if:

1. Case 1: if $x<y$, then $x<s<y$.
2. Case 2: if $y<x$, then $y<s<x$.

Is there a way to define betweeness that is equivalent with the above definition, but wouldn't require two cases to do the proof? I'm thinking that the proof for case #1 and case #2 are so similar (we literally only rename the variables), there must be a way to generalize the definition and do these both in one shot.

Comment: $\min(x,y) < s < \max(x,y)$ for instance ?

Comment: I thought of that, but wouldn't we still have to do both cases independently?

Comment: You could assume without loss of generality that $x < y$. Then you only need to prove case 1.

Comment: @RolandKillian hm, logically speaking, how would you justify the assumption, given that $x,y$ are arbitrary?

Comment: @shintuku, given that your two cases cover every case, we know that either $x < y$ or $y < x$. So, we can assume $x$ is the smaller of the two, and $y$ is the larger. This is sort of the definition of "without loss of generality"; One of the two will be smaller, so assume that it is $x$.

Comment: @RolandKillian that works! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define "$c$ is between $a$ and $b$" as
$$
(c-a)(c-b) < 0.
$$

Then the proof that the midpoint is in between is one line.

You would have to show that the usual definition is a theorem.

Comment: Very cool, where do we usually find such a definition? (I'll be accepting this once the timer allows for it)

Comment: I've never seen it. No one would use it since it's clever but not informative.

Answer (score 2):

$s$ is between $x$ and $y$ iff $$|x-s|+|y-s|=|x-y|$$

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

$s$ is strictly between $x$ and $y$ if and only if $(s-x)(s-y) <0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it's just as good as the accepted one!